# Manually adding content at the end of the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[francais, english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
~\cite{cr:sas:12}
% ------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{alone}{\protect\numberline{}Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{thesis}
% ------------------------------------------
% List of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{alone}{\protect\numberline{}List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of tables
\addcontentsline{toc}{alone}{\protect\numberline{}List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of Definitions
\chapter*{List of Definitions}
\markboth{List of Definitions}{List of Definitions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{alone}{\numberline{}List of Definitions}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{lod}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The table of contents generated is as follows:
[image]

Does anyone know why the lines for `Bibliography`, `List of Figures`, etc. are not well generated? I mean I expect to see something as follows:

```
1 Chapter                                                3
  1.1 Section .........................................  3


Bibliography ..........................................  3
List of Figures .......................................  5
List of Tables ........................................  9
List of Definitions ................................... 11
```

Comment: You haven't told it how to format lines which should be treated as section units of the type `alone`, have you?

Comment: If you want them formatted like entries for sections, specify `section` rather than `alone`.

Comment: Please see my updates...

Comment: Yes? You are still telling it to format the entries as section units of type `alone`. Why do you expect it to read `alone` and realise you mean `section`, if that is what you mean? Why don't you tell it what you mean? To put this another way: what is section unit `alone`? Unlike `chapter`, `section`, `subsection` etc., it is completely unknown to LaTeX. So LaTeX does its best: it has no instructions on what to do, so it just outputs the information without additional formatting. It would be the same if you used `xafgfdgreeqabergegretre` in place of `alone`.

Comment: I understand that it is not `alone` to put as `sec_unit`, but what should I put to return what I expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Format each ToC-entry you manually insert as type `chapter` rather than `alone`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
% ------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Bibliography}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliography{thesis}
% ------------------------------------------
% List of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of tables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of Definitions
\chapter*{List of Definitions}
\markboth{List of Definitions}{List of Definitions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Definitions}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to *not* have the entries indented the way they are, remove the `\protect\numberline{}` macros included in your `\addcontentsline` insertions:

[image]

For adding dots (or leaders) as part of the manually-added ToC-entries, you can insert them as type `dchapter` rather than `chapter` and use the following addition in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\l@dchapter\l@chapter
\patchcmd{\l@dchapter}% <cmd>
  {\hfil}% <search>
  {{\normalfont\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above inserts the dots as leaders (directly taken from the definition of `\@dottedtocline` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)) where formerly it just had `\hfil`. Additionally, in order to make the leaders line up with the `section`-type entries, they have been set in `\normalfont`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Is it possible to have the `...` between the title and the page number? It is OK if there isn't an obvious solution...

Comment: @SoftTimur: See the updated answer.

Comment: the dots aren't spaced the same in the added lines; this might be because the type size is different, but it's unfortunate.  also, the additional entries aren't flush left as they were in the second example and in the original request.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I've updated the answer to correct for that.