# How to hide chapter number, but only for the first chapter?

Tags: formatting, chapters, titles

I want to hide chapter number but only for first chapter. I found many references on how to hide chapter number, it's actually a re-write of how chapter titles are displayed:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
...

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\chapter{Introduction}
```

But after chapter 1, I would like to restore the default way of displaying chapters.
I find so many references on how to hide it, but I haven't spotted one on how to restore it, how can this be done?

(I would imagine a clean way which would be to store default state in some sort of variable and then restoring it, but maybe that's programming bias.)

Comment: Do you really only want to hide the number or do you want to not count it?

Comment: I guess I could "not count it" (how?) (but I still want it to appear in TOC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything else fails, use `chapter*` and then add it to the `toc` manually?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction}
    
    \chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Adding things to the `toc` is explained very well in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208732/118712

BTW: If you do not want the chapter to be indented in the `toc`, i.e. aligned with the text of the other chapters but rather their number remove `\protect\numberline{}`

**EDIT:** If, for whatever twisted reason, you still want the second chapter to be chapter `2` simply add `\stepcounter{chapter}` after the `addcontentsline` command.

Comment: Well I'm actually fine with not having that chapter line in the TOC.
And I had completely forgot about the "*" (getting back to LaTeX after some specific use some time ago.)
But this creates another problem, all the sections in this chapter are not numbered (0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...) in both TOC and text. I'd like them to look like (1, 2, 3,...)

Comment: Or no, sorry, it was fine when they looked like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, but using the "*" breaks this.
Which brings me back to my initial idea, how to \titleformat to revert back to default after skipping one chapter number.

Comment: Ok, I have actually fixed using "*" and \stepcounter{chapter} on the following line. (Combining stuff from your suggestion.

Comment: You can just use `\chapter*{Intro} \stepcounter{chapter}` and it will display the sections as 1.1 and the next chapter will be Chapter 2. Also there will be no TOC entry. Although as a reader I might find that confusing.